# PgAdmin se congela al tratar de eliminar una tabla de la base de datos

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, geolocalización, postgresql-9.3

Tengo problemas con una tabla en mi base de datos la cual estaba vinculada a geoserver. El layer fue eliminado desde geoserver pero sigue viendose la tabla en la base datos. Al intentar eliminarla con DROP TABLE, el programa se congela, de hecho con solo tocar la tabla con el mouse, el programa se congela y solo queda cerrarlo. Alguien sabe de que manera se puede solucionar esto? Muchas gracias!!

Comment: ¿Has probado a reiniciar el programa?

Comment: Si, por supuesto. He probado todo lo que está a mi alcance hasta ahora.

Comment: en qué sistema operativo estás?

Comment: Windows 7 x64. Instale pgAdmin4 y ahora puedo ver las tablas pero no puedo eliminarlas.

Answer (score 1):

Es una pregunta antigua pero recientemente me pasó algo similar. Un par de puntos que pueden ayudar.

Eliminar una `layer` de geoserver no elimina la tabla. Una `layer` es sólo una determinada representación de un origen de datos (un shapefile, un ráster, una vista, una tabla, ...) en geoserver. Eliminarla no elimina la fuente de datos.

En estas situaciones lo más probable es que existe un [lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/explicit-locking.html) sobre la tabla. Es decir que una query o una sesión que la está usando de modo exclusivo.

La solución más bruta suele ser reiniciar. En caso de que no sea viable hay que averiguar si efectivamente la tabla está bloqueada:

```
SELECT pid, relname
FROM pg_locks l
JOIN pg_class t ON l.relation = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r'
WHERE t.relname = 'MI_TABLA';
```

Si sale algún resultado es que está bloqueada y se puede matar el proceso bloqueante con:

```
kill -9 EL_PID
```

Como se indica [en esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317114/postgresql-drop-table-doesnt-work), también puede ser que haya una `pending prepared transaction`:

```
SELECT database, gid FROM pg_prepared_xacts;
ROLLBACK PREPARED 'EL_GID'
```